# How to create django models with custom foreign sets

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a 1:many relationship on two Model classes in my Django application:

```
class CheckList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='checklists')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class CheckListItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='items')
    checklist = models.ForeignKey(WishList, related_name='items')
    is_checked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Most of the time, I want to present a user's checklists and each checklist's items, and it's pretty vanilla.

However, I also want to have a few "virtual checklists" which contain a custom set of list items.

I'd like to do this:

```
def get_checklist_checked(user):
    checklist = CheckList(name='My Checked Items', user=user)
    checklist.items = CheckListItem.objects.filter(user=user, check=True)
    return checklist
```

Of course now, `checklist.items` is an array, whereas usually `checklist.items` is a Manager.

What is the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: Do you want to return the related list of items for the objects when `list.items` is called ? Also,Please use a better variable than `list`

Comment: I made it generic for the purposes of this illustration but I can see how it can get confusing.  Most of the times list.items retrieves the related items (based on FK relationship), but I want to be able to construct transient `list` objects (which are not themselves in the database).  One example transient `list` object would contain all the items with `check=True`.

Comment: Have you considered using a `custom manager` ?

Comment: I'm aware that custom managers can be created for certain model classes, but not sure how I would use it in this case.  The examples I've seen were for, say, adding a new method to the manager.  But here, I guess I'm wanting to override `checklist.items.all()`?  And it seems like that might be too complex for this situation.

I guess another option is to use a second class, containing an `items` array, to which I translate both transient and persisted `CheckList` objects.

Comment: Agreed, but in my opinion, a manager would do what you intend to do, and keeps the code cleaner. Another approach would be to define an instance method, which would return related checklist items with the filter criteria

Comment: How would I use a custom manager to provide a different set of items?  I'm trying to keep consumers of the CheckList instances agnostic to whether this is a transient object or not.

Answer (score 0):

I learned more about [custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) and I understand how I could use a custom manager to predefine a query.

However, I am essentially asking to change the manager used for related access of `CheckListItem` only in certain instances of the `CheckList` class, and I don't think it's possible.

What I decided on was that since I already have a set of DTO methods which convert the models to dicts (because these are going straight into a JSON response), that I would not use the CheckList class at all for transient CheckLists.  Instead I would fetch the filtered items directly and code the DTO method to accept either a CheckList object or the checklist name and items.

```
def get_checklist(request, checklist_id):
    #get a special 'transient' checklist
    if checklist_id == 'checkedItems':
        items = CheckListItem.objects.filter(is_checked=True)
        dto = getCheckListDto(items=items, name="Checked Items")
    #get a regular checklist
    else:
        cl = CheckList.objects.get(checklist_id)
        dto = getCheckListDto(checklist=cl)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dto), content_type="application/json")

#Can pass in either a checklist object, or name + items array
def getCheckListDto(checklist=None, items=[], name=None):
    if checklist is not None:
        items = checklist.items.all()
        name = checklist.name

    return { 
        'name': name,
        'items': [getCheckListItemDto(i) for i in items]
    }
```

The only place where I could see using a custom manager would be to provide a manager to fetch only is_checked checklist items, so that I could just do `CheckListItem.checked_objects.all()`.  But since the filter is so simple I didn't bother.

If anyone has a better idea, especially if I'm missing a way that custom managers could help here, feel free to submit an answer.